# How can I make a ProcessingJS canvas encompass the etnire webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

Maybe I'm just missing something, but every time I've seen a website use ProcessingJS a "Size(x,y)" has to be set to create a workable area within the canvas.  I'm sure the height and width of the canvas can use CSS to set the values to 100% but I cannot find a way to make the size of the workable area within the canvas to be the entire canvas even as the user resizes the browser window.

My plan is to use ProcessingJS' draw function to create an intractable background for a webpage but maybe I am approaching this from the wrong angle.  Any help or tips would be appreciated, even if that help points me to learning to use a different library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
```

Then use those values to set x & y.